Problem with datasource connection OCI with spring boot 2.1.8 and wallet
I have a web application with springboot 2.1.8 that connects to 2 databases, one of them in OCI using a WALLET.
My configuration in the properties file is as follows (I leave out some sensitive data):
#Configuration to OCI
datasource1.spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
datasource1.spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@bddociaddv?TNS_ADMIN=/u02/Admin/domains/domain1/wls12c/props/bddoci
datasource1.spring.datasource.username=username
datasource1.spring.datasource.password=pass


NOTE: in the 'jdbc-url' property, the path indicated in 'TNS_ADMIN' points to a folder that has the unzipped configuration.
In my POM file I have this dependency to ojdbc:
        <!-- Uncomment this when using Oracle Credentials Wallet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>${oracle.ojdbc.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>simplefan</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

where: ${oracle.ojdbc.version} = <oracle.ojdbc.version>[19,20)</oracle.ojdbc.version>
The problem is that the application does not wake up, and the log indicates the following:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-05-17 16:22:19,040 ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] Application run failed
# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxxxxEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/domain/subdomain/repository1/model/XXXXXXDatasourceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'XXXXXXXEntityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.**

The web maintainer should connect to the OCI database without any problems :(

To use the wallet, you need oraclepki artifact in your pom and the property name is datasource1.spring.datasource.url not jdbc-url.
